# Twitter in Ruby on Rails - 500 Internal Server Error: "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-oauth

all.

I'm working my way through teaching myself Oauth-Twitter and the Twitter gem in Ruby on Rails. I'm still fairly fresh to this despite having completed a bootcamp on Rails dev.

I was able to get OAuth - Twitter to function properly but now that I'm trying to tweet from the application I get the following:

`Twitter::Error::Forbidden at /tweets
Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.`

The error gets thrown on `client.update(tweet)` from my `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
      user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
      user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
      user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
      user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
      user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['Twitter']
      user.oauth_token=auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.oauth_secret=auth_hash.credentials.secret
      user.save!
      user
    end
  end

  def tweet(tweet)
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = Rails.application.config.twitter_key
      config.consumer_secret = Rails.application.config.twitter_secret
      config.access_token = oauth_token
      config.access_token_secret = oauth_secret
    end
    client.update(tweet)
  end
end
```

And my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151018214537) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider",     null: false
    t.string   "uid",          null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.string   "oauth_secret"
  end

  add_index "users", ["provider", "uid"], name:    "index_users_on_provider_and_uid", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["provider"], name: "index_users_on_provider"
  add_index "users", ["uid"], name: "index_users_on_uid"

end
```

Any help you could provide would be fantastic. You can find all other information at my [Github Repo](https://github.com/InsomniaNoir/kronoTweeter/tree/sendtweets)

Comment: Have you verified that your environment variables are actually getting set?

Answer (score 0):

After an assist I discovered I was not accessing the keys I had stored in my application.yml (yay, Figaro!). `user.rb` has been updated to this:

```
  def tweet(tweet)
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
      config.consumer_secret = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
      config.access_token = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
      config.access_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
    end
    client.update(tweet)
  end
end
```

And the test Tweet through my account worked perfectly.